# Using async with c# windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, api, bing-api

I'm new to working with API's so bare with me. I'm trying to load 3 images into picture boxes by using the Bing Image Search API but I'm having trouble with my async method. From my POV everything looks like it should be working just fine. (I used this documentation for my code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-image-search/quickstarts/sdk/image-search-client-library-csharp). Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
    private static string _subscriptionKey = "MY_API_KEY";
    private static string _baseUri = "https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/images/search";    
    private static string searchString = "car";
    private static string _clientIdHeader = null;
    private const string QUERY_PARAMETER = "?q=";  // Required
    private const string MKT_PARAMETER = "&mkt=";  // Strongly suggested
private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {

            try
            {

                // Remember to encode the q query parameter.
                var queryString = QUERY_PARAMETER + Uri.EscapeDataString(searchString);
                queryString += MKT_PARAMETER + "en-us";
                HttpResponseMessage response = await MakeRequestAsync(queryString);
                _clientIdHeader = response.Headers.GetValues("X-MSEdge-ClientID").FirstOrDefault();
                // This example uses dictionaries instead of objects to access the response data.
                var contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Dictionary<string, object> searchResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(contentString);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    PrintImages(searchResponse);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }

            async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeRequestAsync(string queryString)
            {
                string count = "3";
                string offset = "0";

                var client = new HttpClient();
                
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", _subscriptionKey);
                return await client.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}q={1}&count={1}", _baseUri + queryString, count, offset));
            }


            void PrintImages(Dictionary<string, object> response)
            {
                
                var images = response["value"] as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken;
                foreach (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken image in images)
                {
                    string imagePic = (image["contentUrl"]).ToString();
                    optionOnePicture.ImageLocation = imagePic;
                    optionTwoPicture.ImageLocation = imagePic;                      
                    optionThreePicture.ImageLocation = imagePic;                      
               
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: What's the problem. Why are you calling `Wait` on the task returned by `RunAsync`, why not `await` it

Comment: I'm following along with the documentation and it works on a c# console app ( it returns 3 image URLs) but I'm not sure why/ how its not being able to be shown in the picture boxes. I'm just at a loss right now

Comment: So what kind of bad documentation is that for `RunAsync().Wait();`? A correct example should show you how to hook an async event handler and start from there (like [my post](https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-replace-backgroundworker-with-async-await-and-tasks-80d7c8ed89dc)).

Comment: Unlikely to bite you here but HttpClient is supposed to be single instance (or limited instance, one per session if you're doing some sort of "logged in N times to the same website" type parallel interaction sequences), by the way

Comment: Make the event handler async and then await RunAsync. .Wait() in the winform will cause a deadlock. Secondly have the method return the desired value and set the controls after the await. Trying to access UI controls within an await will cause cross thread access violation.

Comment: Don't ever mix Console async code with code run in an event-driven platform. Don't use `.Wait` or `.Result` (or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` for that matter) here. -- What @CaiusJard is referring to is also quite important. If, for some reason, you need to initialize locally a HttpClient object instead of using a static Field, you need to dispose of it.

Comment: Often examples show the use of HttpClient like that. It's a shortcut, to demonstrate some of its methods and focusing of these, not the overall functionality of this class. A generic Console project is used. In practice, you should never create new instances of that class, unless its just *one shot*, once in a while, to perform a single upload/download/query of something, then everything is disposed of and destroyed. -- After a while and some testing, you'll find out that you probably need a factory or a well-handled static object anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Don't block on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Instead, use `await`:

```
private async void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await RunAsync();
  ...
}
```

Side note: this code is using `async void` because the method is an event handler. Normally, you would want to [avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).